# gentran map

Tags: edi

Is there a way to invoke gentran server to translate a EDI 837 file to a custom format thru a batch script. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used GENTRAN:Server for several years, so please excuse any fuzziness on my part.

I think there is an executable called unattend.exe that you can use to execute session files. I believe you can call it from a batch file like this:

c:\*pathname*\unattend.exe c:\*session file pathname*\*sessionname*.ses

More recent versions might have something better, but this might be worth a try.